# Error when searching for a specific character in a specific index of a string that comes from a textfile(counting paragraphs in a textfile)

Tags: arrays, text-files, pascal, lazarus, paragraph

I have a problem with searching specific characters in a textfile. The problem comes from the task of counting the paragraphs in a textfile. The idea is obvious - two paragraphs in a textfile are divided by a blankline, that means that the first character in that line is ASCII#13, so if I make a procedure that goes through

The idea is obvious - two paragraphs in a textfile are divided by a blank line, that means that the first character in that line is ASCII#13, so if I make a procedure that goes through every line in the textfile and if the first character in the line is ASCII#13 then the counter increases by 1. But when I do that I get an external: SIGSEGV error on the line when I run the program. This is the code -

```
procedure paragraphs(name:string) ;
var
line:string;
paragraphs:integer;
file:textfile
begin
assignfile(file, name)     ;
reset(file);
paragraphs:=0;
while not eof(file) do
   begin
     readln(file,line);
     if line[1]=#13  then     //here is the error
     paragraphs:=paragraphs+1;
   end;
end;
```

Now what is weird though is that I have a very similar procedure that counts the total number of words, that works on the same basis and works fine with no errors

```
procedure words(name:string);
var 
insideword:boolean  ;
x,words:integer;
file:textfile;
line:string;
begin
assignfile(file, name);
reset(file);
words:=0;
while not eof(file) do
begin
  insideword:=false;
readln(file,line);
for x:=1 to length(line) do
begin
if line[x]=' ' then insideword:=false   //no problem here
else begin
if insidewords=false then words:=words+1;
insidewords:=true;
end;
end;
end;
end;
```

I thought that strings are basically arrays of char, but I think that strings being dynamic arrays in this case prevents me from using a specific index, though it basically worked in the Words procedure and I'm using the same idea - searching a dynamic array for a specific character. But here I need to search for a specific character in the first index of the line. Why doesnt the above Procedure Paragraphs work? Any ideas on how to correct the procedure so that it displays the number of paragraphs in a textfile?

Comment: You aren't ever going to see line feeds in these strings. Ever. That's the point of ReadLn. Do consider learning to debug. If you would inspect the variables you'll see what they contain.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this the wrong way.

`ReadLn` does not return the line-end character(s), so when you try to access the first character of an empty line, you get an access violation, because there is no "first" character to access via `Line[1]`.  If you really want to access the file character-by-character, use `Read()` rather than `ReadLn()`.

To search through a string as per the title of your q, use the `Pos()` function to search a string for a character or sub-string.  See the OLH for  usage.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. I thought a change of the error line to something like this   `if Pos(#13,line)=1 then paragraphs:=paragraphs+1;`  would work, but it displays zero, even though the textfile has 2 paragraphs.

Comment: Well, though whole point of `readLn` is to relieve you of the chore of continually looking for end-of-line characters.

Comment: Changing `ReadLn()` to `Read()` makes the program not return anything as it is continuously running, as well as adding a `while not eoln(file)`, so I have to use `ReadLn()`

Comment: @Johnny Yes, use `ReadLn()` but check `Length(line)` instead of `line[1]...` if length is 0 and you are not at eof it must be a new paragraph.

Comment: I think only a masochist would use `Read()` when `ReadLn()` exists to do the hard work for you.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Well this probably calls for a new question. Your answer works, but I realized that my idea works only if there is only one line separating each paragraph. If there are multiple, then it counts +1 for every one of the lines separating the paragraphs which ruins the result. And once again I have no idea how to prevent this, oh well…

Comment: @Johnny As in an answer to a previous post of yours, use a e.g. `InNewPara` boolean that you set the first time you see an empty line and clear when you see a non-empty line. If the variable is true, you simply don't increment paragraphs.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Yes after scratching my head for a few mins I realized I could basically just do the same thing that i did in the `Words` procedure, which is what you are suggesting. Thank you very much for help.